# Accessing Quire API: Authorization code expired

Tags: quire-api

I performed some tests with the API (by the way thanks a lot for that ;-)) and I struggle with the following issue: `{'error': 'invalid_grant', 'error_description': "The 'code' provided was invalid."}` If I run into the manual process to get the authorization code and try with the new one it's work but after test it's doesn't work again. Can you tell me the reasons that can expire this code? In the doc I only see about the token expiration. Is that because my app is in "Unpublished"? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You need to refresh the access token when the token is already expired (the token will be expired after 1 hour). For more details, please visit this blog post: https://quire.io/blog/p/Create-Your-Quire-App-with-Quire-API.html#refreshing-tokens